# Node Express route to new window location upon ajax success

Tags: javascript, node.js

Upon hitting my web page through the initial url `/` I have an input where a password is needed to view the next page. I am not quite sure how to redirect the user to the next page upon a successful password match.

Client call:

```
var urlToCall = baseUrl + '/info?pass=' + password;
$.ajax({
  'url' : urlToCall,
  'type' : 'GET'
})
.done(function(data){
  console.log(data)
})
.fail(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Node/express:

```
var info = require('./routes/info');
app.use('/info', info);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     //... logic to check password and such

    res.render('info', { title: 'Book Info' });
})
```

The thing is I am returned a string of html from the file `info.ejs` on a success. Now if I go to the url in the browser instead of through the password `https://myUrl.com/info?pass=mypassword` it successfully routes me to it. So through the ajax check, how can I do the same?

`res.render` is only giving me the html back, but I need to rout the user to this page.

Thanks for any help

Comment: use [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var info = require('./routes/info');
app.use('/info', info);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('input-passwordpage.html');

})'

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
         //... logic to check password and such
      if(req.body.password === "password")
        res.json{('info', { title: 'Book Info' }});
      else 
        res.json({});

    })'




var urlToCall = baseUrl + '/info?pass=' + password;
$.ajax({
  'url' : urlToCall,
  'type' : 'POST'
})
.done(function(data){

  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(data);
//according to returned data structure you can access its properties.
  if(data.info) {
    $.html('you html here '); 
    //you can also use $.load depending upon your requirements
    /// also window.location.href will also work depending upon your logic and requirement

   }
})
.fail(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: When I try to parse the data sent back I get:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: ok use JSON.stringify before parsing. also if there '<' angle bracket it means you are receiving html instead of json. check in chrome network request and view data.

Comment: Alright. I got it working. I just replace the current view with the html that is passed back. Not forwarding to a new path